# Is it possible to create a Matlab instance as an administrator?

Tags: c#, matlab, interface, com, uac

I'm new to working with Matlab and I've spent the day trying to get Matlab to interact with my C# application.
As it stands I can send commands using the MLapp interface like so:

```
MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();
```

My problem is when I try execute a command to save data:

```
string result = matlab.Execute(inputVectorCommand);
            matlab.Execute("save('saveTest.mat','x')");
```

I get the following error:

```
Error using save
Unable to write file ytest.mat: permission denied.
```

I believe this is as the instance of Matlab is created with the highest UAC. Does anybody know a solution for this problem?

Comment: 1) Start matlab via "Run as administrator" and try save via ML-Command shell. Is it possible? 2) Start matlab via "Run as administrator" and connect to the session, is saving possible now? 3) Verify that current directory (pwd) is correct.

Comment: I cant connect to an instance other than the one specified in my code so using Run as Administrator doesn't seem to be an option

Comment: You can not connect to an already opened ML-Instance? Okay, that is a strange ML-Connection. I am not using this but another 3rd party Matab connection, so I'm not common with this solution. What's about 1) running cod manually and 3) checking current directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably the Windows security feature known as [**User Interface Privelage Isolation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Interface_Privilege_Isolation). This is where a lower integrity process is not allowed to communicate with a higher integrity process.

This was added to Windows Vista to prevent what's known as a [**Shatter Attack**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shatter_attack).

The security concern is that a malicious application can try to communicate with an elevated MatLab process, possibly using it to write to secure locations.

For example, your C# application is attempting to use MatLab in order to save files on the hard drive.